# Read registry value by DesktopAppConvertor at conversion time

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am try to convert my desktop Exe to Universal Windows App using DesktopAppConvertor. My Desktop Application Setup (exe) is a common setup ( .exe ) for both 32 bit and 64 bit (It use separate dll and exe for 32 bit and separate dll and exe for 64 bit). At installation time my desktop application setup (exe) first read the registry and check the Microsoft office OUTLOOK.EXE path then check that outlook is 32 bit or 64 bit then according this outlook version installed 32 bit (exe and dll) or 64 bit( exe and dll). 
When I try to convert my Desktop App into universal Windows App then desktopAppconvertor create package for 32 bit by default while my Microsoft office OUTLOOK.EXE is 64 bit.
So How can I read registry vale for (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OUTLOOK.EXE') using DesktopAppConvertor/Desktop Bridge and can check it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

My Desktop Exe found following registry value at run time:
Read Success SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ Exist
List of subkeys:
cmmgr32.exe,dfshim.dll,excel.exe,firefox.exe,fsquirt.exe,GROOVE.EXE,IEDIAG.EXE
IEDIAGCMD.EXE,IEXPLORE.EXE,infopath.exe,install.exe,licensemanagershellext.exe,Lync.exe,mip.exe,mplayer2.exe,MSACCESS.EXE,MsoHtmEd.exe,msoxmled.exe,MSPUB.EXE,OneNote.exe,OUTLOOK.EXE,pbrush.exe,powerpnt.exe,PowerShell.exe,setup.exe,
SnippingTool.exe,table30.exe,TabTip.exe,vstoee.dll,wab.exe,wabmig.exe,Winword.exe,wmplayer.exe,WORDPAD.EXE,WRITE.EXE
Read Success Outlook.exe Exist

While DesktopAppConvertor Exe found following registry value at Exe conversion time :
Read Success SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ Exist
List of subkeys:

cmmgr32.exe , dfshim.dll , fsquirt.exe , IEDIAG.EXE, IEDIAGCMD.EXE, IEXPLORE.EXE, install.exe, licensemanagershellext.exe, mip.exe,mplayer2.exe
pbrush.exe, PowerShell.exe,setup.exe,SnippingTool.exe,table30.exe
TabTip.exe, wab.exe, wabmig.exe,wmplayer.exe, WORDPAD.EXE,WRITE.EXE.
Why Microsoft Office products (excel,Word,Outlook etc.) exe are missing? 
How can I read/access "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OUTLOOK.EXE" ?

Thanks

Comment: I found the similar case in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ae7dad5b-b0d5-47be-b70c-49376eed0ffd/uwpdacdesktopappconverterexe-stuck-on-verbose-starting-the-isolated-environment?forum=wpdevelop), and it has reply, Please keep pay attention to follow up.

Comment: Yes but my problem is not solved.

Comment: MSFT will continue following up, please pay attention to the update.